Ajax Posting string to controller action returns 404
On keyup I call a JavaScript function, this function should make a call to a controller action and return a result but I am getting a 404 error. I have breakpoints at the top of the controller action but never hit any. I assume it is not getting in because the type or something to do with the data being sent.
It is coded in C# MVC .NET 6
Java Script::::
function GetThingsContaining() { 

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "GetThingsContaining/MyController",
        data: { searchCriteria: "afd" },
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            //do work if successful
        },
        error: function (data) {
            alert("Well that stinks")
        },
    }); 
}

   Controller Action
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult GetThingsContaining(string searchCriteria) {
            return PartialView("~/Views/Investments/_SearchDataList.cshtml", returnModel);
        }

I place a break point on the return but never hit it. In dev tools it gives me a 404

Shouldn't the URL be "MyController/GetThingsContaining"?  The action is on the controller, not the other way around.

This is interesting. So it does work now. But All my other ajax work and they have it with the controller being last

Somewhere in your code are your routing rules defined. Find and check them.

@ItsDataMiner If you are making the call from your .cshtml view file then you can use the helper: url: "@Url.Action("GetThingsContaining","MyController")"

I am doing it in a external Js file but it turned out it is because I have "Controller/Action"
instead of "/Controller/Action". After updating it they all worked perfectly as expected

try this, use [Frombody] in the controller, then try to request like this
fetch('/MyController/GetThingsContaining', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({ searchCriteria: 'afd' }),
    })
    .then(response => {
        if (!response.ok) {
            throw new Error('Network response was not ok');
        }
        return response.json();
    })
    .then(data => {
        // do work if successful
    })


also you can send the data directly in the URL, something like this
/MyController/GetThingsContaining?searchCriteria=${"afd"}
